# UR Driver Error after catkin_make (CMake Error)

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to build the Universal Robots ROS Driver on ROS Melodic Ubuntu 18.04 (VirtualBox VM), but when I try to build the workspace with `catkin_make` I get the error shown below.

What should I do to solve this? Thank you

```
UR Driver Error after catkin_make

CMake Warning at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'gazebo' but neither 'gazebo_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
'gazebo_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
myproject_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:41 (catkin_package)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:305 (message):
 catkin_package() include dir 'include' does not exist relative to
 '/home/<user>/catkin_ws/src/myproject_gazebo'
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
 myproject_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:41 (catkin_package)


 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 See also "/home/<user>/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
 See also "/home/<user>/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
 Makefile:3708: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
 make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
 Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348736/ur-driver-error-after-catkin_make-(cmake-error)/) by [Vuro H](https://answers.ros.org/users/52882/vuro-h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We see this:

```
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  myproject_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:41 (catkin_package)
```

note the `myproject_gazebo` in the second line of the Call Stack.

It's likely you have a `catkin_package(... CATKIN_DEPENDS gazebo ..)` in the `CMakeLists.txt` of your `myproject_gazebo` package, but you don't have a `find_package(gazebo)` or added it to your `find_package(Catkin .. COMPONENTS ..)` call.

As-is, I don't believe this is a problem with `ur_robot_driver`, but with `myproject_gazebo`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vuro H](https://answers.ros.org/users/52882/vuro-h/) on 2020-04-19**:
Thanks a lot for your help, you were right with this